# Fixed bar width, tick interval in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I have problem fixing the width of the bar and the tick interval in Highstock when I try to change zoom level in range selector. I tried to search online for many solution but none of them solve the exact problem I have. :(

I want the 1w to perform as it is now. I do not want the tick interval to become hourly due to the config I add for day option: 
http://jsfiddle.net/neo_6053/LwcL205p/3/
`xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime', 
    ordinal: false, 
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '<b>%b %e</b>'
    }
  }`

But I want the 1d to have tick interval of 1 hour and I want all the gap, bar width to be fixed. I tried many options but still failed to do so. You can see the chart messed up when drag to the far left.
http://jsfiddle.net/neo_6053/LwcL205p/5/
`xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime', 
    ordinal: false,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    tickInterval: 3600000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '<b>%b %e</b>'
    }
  }`

My last resort will be to get the service to return all the missing date if Highchart cannot support that. But I wish not.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code inside series configuration should solve your problem:

```
pointRange: 3600 * 1000
```

It forces Highcharts to set the range for every point to one hour. By default it's computed automatically and it seems that sometimes ranges are higher than desired (that's why there're empty spaces in your example).

---

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/svkm4un3/

**API reference:** http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.pointRange